# Integer divisions of a number

Tags: java, algorithm, math, numbers, double

How do I split a number into equal parts or as close to equal as possible. See example below:

If I have a value of 61 that i want to distribute between two groups, it would be 30.5 and 30.5. Doubles (decimals) are no good, so in this regard the closest split is 30 and 31.

Similarly 42 / 5 = 8.4, however I need the system to return (8, 8, 8, 9, 9) which is the closest split with whole numbers.

Solved it guys:

```
        if(sum % numberOfTeams != 0) {
        al.add(0, sNOT);
    for(int i = 0; i < numberOfTeams - 1;  i++) {
        int remover = sum - sNOT;
        if(remover % (sNOT + 1) == 0) {
            al.add(i+1, sNOT + 1);
        }else {
         al.add(i + 1, sNOT);

        }

     }
}
```

}

Comment: Not taking away from an interesting problem, but curious as to why a question with no effort gets several upvotes?

Comment: I agree entirely with @Dukeling.. I had a little squabble about this on the meta site yesterday. Interesting questions are more likely to receive upvotes (regardless of shown effort) than uninteresting ones.

Comment: @achAmháin That is typical of the algorithm tag.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a solution which entirely uses `Arrays`, a little shorter with no loops. Validity check should also be applied as suggested above

```
    int value = 42;
    int groups = 5;

    int residue = value % groups;
    int[] res = new int[groups];
    int division = value / groups;
    Arrays.fill(res, 0, residue, division +1);
    Arrays.fill(res, residue, res.length, division);

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(res));
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's one solution:

```
public static int[] closestSplit(int intToSplit, int noOfGroups) {

    int[] result = new int[noOfGroups];
    Arrays.fill(result, intToSplit / noOfGroups);
    for (int i = 0; i < intToSplit % noOfGroups; i++) {
        result[i]++;
    }
    return result;

}


// usage:
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(closestSplit(42, 5)));
```

Basically, it creates an array of length `noOfGroups` first, then fills that with the integer division of `intToSplit` and `noOfGroups`. Next, it adds one to the first `intToSplit mod noOfGroups` elements of the array.

If you require the result to be ordered in ascending order, you can loop from the end of the array or use `Arrays.sort`.

Answer (score 1):

The major thing you need to consider while solving this question is remainders.

From the example above, we intend to split 61 into 2, `61 / 2` gives a remainder of **1**. Since we're splitting into two groups, only 1 out of these 2 groups have to be `((int) 61 / 2) + 1`. The remaining (one) group can be `((int) 61 / 2)`.

Also, consider splitting 42 into 5, `42 / 5` gives a remainder of **2**. Since, we're splitting into 5 groups, only 2 out of these 5 groups have to be `((int) 42 / 5) + 1`. The remaining (three) groups can be `((int) 42 / 5)`.

Here's the code:

```
public int[] spitNumbers(int number, int groups){

    int[] result = new int[groups];  //The array we'd return at the end

    int shift = number % groups;  //I used this to check the remainder.

    for(int i = 0; i < result.length; i++){

    /* The if-statement below checks for two things:
       - if the remainder is zero
       - if we've reached the shifting stage.
    */
        if((shift == 0) || (i < shift)){
            result[i] = number / groups;
        }

    // The else statement starts being fired when the shifting stage has been reached.

        else{
            result[i] = (number / groups) + 1;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

I hope this helps.. Merry coding!

Answer (score -1):

Please have a look at this solution, I little tested, it works.

```
public static int[] number(int number, int divider) {
    if (number == 0 || number < divider) {
        return new int[]{0};
    }
    if (number == 1 || number == divider) {
        return new int[]{1};
    }
    double r = (double) number / divider;
    int upperCount = number % divider;
    return IntStream.range(0, divider).map(i ->{
        if (i < upperCount) {
            return (int) Math.ceil(r);
        }
        return (int) Math.floor(r);
    }).toArray();
}
```

p.s. little simplfied